# Searching in cache data gives array first index 1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7, laravel-5.8

```
$this->getCachedCategories();
//Above code Stores the data in cache for future use. So, it goes to the database only 
//one time and next time pick the data from cache. So far everything is good.

//I have a search criteria which is in the form of array. I filter above cache data based 
//upon the search criteria and gets the data.
foreach ($userInputsForFilter as $key => $value) {
    $this->Categories = $this->Categories->where($key, $value);
}
```

Here is the screenshot. If you notice the data retrieved has first index from 1 instead of 0. Actually the second record came up after cache data was filtered.

[image]

Can you please tell why this happens when searching the cache data? This not happening when going to the database.

## Array to JSON Code

```
$CategoryResponse = $this->iCategory->All([], []);
return \Response::json($CategoryResponse, 200);
```

Comment: This can happen when converting a `Collection` to JSON; if the ID is used to index the array (associative, `1 => ...` instead of `0 => ...`), then it treats it as an object instead of an array. Can you post the code where `$this->Categories` is being converted to JSON?

Comment: Cool; try with `return \Response::json(array_values($CategoryResponse->toArray()), 200);`; should convert the `Collection` to an array, then re-index (convert associative to 0-based indexed array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel's `Collections`, and arrays in general in PHP can be associative, meaning that the first index can be something that isn't necessarily 0. When converting to JSON via `Response::json()`, or `return response->json()`, it can be treated as an `object` instead of an array in JS. To handle this, convert the `Collection` to an array, and change to an `indexed` one via PHP's `array_values()` function:

```
$CategoryResponse = $this->iCategory->All([], []);
return response()->json(array_values($CategoryResponse->toArray()), 200);
// Older Laravel syntax
// return \Response::json(array_values($CategoryResponse->toArray()), 200);
```

In the JSON response, it should display correct as an array with `0` as the first index.